# ASP.NET Core 3.1: Use Newtonsoft JSON only in some controllers

Tags: asp.net-core, serialization, json.net, system.text.json

I have an ASP.NET Core 3.1 application where I use

```cs
services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson();
```

to use the Newtonsoft JSON serializer. Unfortunately I cannot switch completely to `System.Text.Json` in one step.

Is there a way to put an attribute like

```cs
[NewtonsoftJson]
public class MyController : Controller
{
   // ...
```

on those controllers that I could not yet migrate -- and only use Newtonsoft for these controllers?

Comment: You could write your own input/output formatters. You have the httpcontext available there and with a bit of fiddling (might require some custom middleware to set a flag though) you could decide whether to forward it to the newtonsoft or stj implementations. You might also have to do the same for the openapi documentation generation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description, I suggest you could consider using the ActionFilterAttribute to achieve your requirement.

Like below :

```
public class NewtonsoftJsonFormatterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
   public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
   {
       if (context.Result is ObjectResult objectResult)
       {
           var jsonOptions = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<IOptions<MvcNewtonsoftJsonOptions>>();
 
            objectResult.Formatters.RemoveType<SystemTextJsonOutputFormatter>();
            objectResult.Formatters.Add(new NewtonsoftJsonOutputFormatter(
                jsonOptions.Value.SerializerSettings,
                context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<ArrayPool<char>>(),
                context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IOptions<MvcOptions>>().Value));
        }
        else
        {
             base.OnActionExecuted(context);
        }
    }
}
```

More details, you could refer to this [article](https://blogs.taiga.nl/martijn/2020/05/28/system-text-json-and-newtonsoft-json-side-by-side-in-asp-net-core/).